# Появление блока без сдвига нижних

Tags: html, css, hover, position

Имеется следующая разметка:

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
}

.container .item {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container .item .title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.container .item .button {
  display: none;
}

.container .item:hover .title {
  white-space: normal;
}

.container .item:hover .button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Длинный длинный длинный заголовок товара</div>
    <div class="price">12345.67 USD</div>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#">Купить</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Длинный длинный длинный заголовок товара</div>
    <div class="price">12345.67 USD</div>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#">Купить</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Длинный длинный длинный заголовок товара</div>
    <div class="price">12345.67 USD</div>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#">Купить</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5cfwb5bu/

Задача: сделать так, чтобы по ховеру на `.item` отображался полный заголовок и кнопка, но при этом нижестоящие блоки `.item` не должны сдвигаться вниз.

Знаю про `position: absolute`, но не пойму как правильно применить.

Comment: Я перевёл SCSS в CSS чтобы можно быть прямо здесь запускать.

Comment: А что значит не сдвигались вниз? Просто по умолчанию чтобы были пробелы?

Comment: Это верные размеры блока? При таком кол-ве текста в .title при ховере он будет перекрывать кнопку

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov идея в том, чтобы по ховеру часть .title, которая не влезла, и все ниже ее отображалось поверх нижнего .item, не сдвигая его вниз.

Comment: @Cheg первоначальные размеры высоты .item известны - это одна строка .title + .price

Comment: @PavelSokolov а кол-во строк текста в .title по ховеру?

Comment: @Cheg а это неизвестно. Длина заголовка может быть любой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сделать так: т.к. кол-во изначально видимого контента известно, можно задать блокам фиксированную высоту, а все его содержимое поместить в еще один контейнер - таким образом по ховеру "новый" контент не будет двигать нижестоящие блоки. И никаких `position:absolute` не нужно.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
}

.container .item {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  height: 2em;
}

.container .item .hover {
  background: #fff;
}

.container .item .title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  margin: 0;
}

.container .item .button {
  display: none;
}

.container .item:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}

.container .item:hover .hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container .item:hover .title {
  white-space: normal;
}

.container .item:hover .button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="hover">
      <div class="title">Длинный длинный длинный заголовок товара</div>
      <div class="price">12345.67 USD</div>
      <div class="button">
        <a href="#">Купить</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="hover">
      <div class="title">Длинный длинный длинный заголовок товара</div>
      <div class="price">12345.67 USD</div>
      <div class="button">
        <a href="#">Купить</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="hover">
      <div class="title">Длинный длинный длинный заголовок товара</div>
      <div class="price">12345.67 USD</div>
      <div class="button">
        <a href="#">Купить</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать абсолютное позиционирование для `item` при hover и сдвигать нижний блок на нужную высоту прошлого блока.

```css
.container {
  width: 200px;
  /* для абсолютное позиционирование относительно данного контейнера */
  position: relative;
}

.container .item {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.container .item .title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.container .item:hover {
  /* абсолютное позиционирование */
  position: absolute;
  /* просто для демонстрации */
  background-color: red;
}

/* сдвигаем нижний блок на нужное расстояние */
.container .item:hover + .item {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.container .item .button {
  display: none;
}

.container .item:hover .title {
  white-space: normal;
}

.container .item:hover .button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Длинный длинный длинный заголовок товара</div>
    <div class="price">12345.67 USD</div>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#">Купить</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Длинный длинный длинный заголовок товара</div>
    <div class="price">12345.67 USD</div>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#">Купить</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <div class="title">Длинный длинный длинный заголовок товара</div>
    <div class="price">12345.67 USD</div>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#">Купить</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```